# Problema al recibir "data" de ajax en controller laravel por metodo get

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

he estado intentando recibir los datos en mi controlador pero me da un error 500 y dice que se enviaron 0 argumentos y se esperaba 1 por lo que la función no puede ejecutarse, este es mi codigo del javascript

```
function cargarDatos(ano,trimestre) {
var formato = new Intl.NumberFormat();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('trimestre',trimestre);
formData.append('ano',ano);

$.ajax({
    url: "/reportes/cargarSliders",
   data:formData,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        //algo
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});}
```

Y este es mi controller donde se recibe la data que envia el ajax

```
public function cargarSliders ($request) {

        $ano = $request->get('ano');
        $trimestre = $request->get('trimestre');
        $datos = $this->datos($ano,$trimestre);
        return response()->json(['datos'=>$datos]);

}
```

Comment: La petición debe ser get o post?

Comment: Por parte de laravel, tienes que especificarle la clase Illuminate\Http\Request para que la variable que inyectas en la función sea una instancia de esa clase. Luego podrás usar los métodos de esa clase, como por ejemplo $request->get('ano');

Comment: si uso la clase, y la inyecto como (Request $request) pero me envia vacio, el problema está en que el ajax no está enviando la data, por lo que el controller no lo recibe, si quito el "data: formData" del ajax, y quito el parametro $request de la funcion, el ajax funciona

Comment: Quite el codigo del succes para hacerlo menos engorroso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow :)

Se me ocurre que, por ejemplo, si estás enviando un ID para realizar alguna operación con él, deberías de tener una ruta como:

```
url: "/reportes/cargarSliders/54" // Solo por poner un ejemplo
```

Y en la declaración de tu función tendrías algo como esto:

```
public function cargarSliders($id)
```

El parámetro `id` debe de declararse en tu ruta en el archivo `web.php`, de esta manera:

```
Route::get('/reportes/cargarSliders/{id}', 'YourController@cargarSliders');
```

Así es como funcionaría con el método GET.

Para tu ejemplo, como son solo dos variables, en tu AJAX tendría una `url` como la siguiente:

```
url: "/reportes/cargarSliders/2020/2" //Año 2020 en el segundo trimestre
```

De manera que en tu archivo `web.php` declares la ruta como:

```
Route::get('/reportes/cargarSliders/{ano}/{trimestre}', 'YourController@cargarSliders');
```

Y tu función sería declarada así:

```
public function cargarSliders($ano, $trimestre)
```

Y listo, simples parámetros, en vez de usar un `Request`

Comment: gracias, me funcionó, es que no sabia que ese tipo de parametros se tienen que enviar por la url cuando es get y gracias por la bienvenida :)

Comment: De nada, considera votar arriba por mi respuesta :)